# how to add snow flow effect in android?

Tags: android, animation, paint

I  am trying to add snow flow effect. but not succeed 
I tried to do the effect of continuously flow the snow. 
is it possible? if yes than please give suggestion.

my code is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int COLOR_MAX = 0xff;

    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Bitmap imagebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.hydrangeas);    
        applySnowEffect(imagebitmap);

    }
    Bitmap applySnowEffect(Bitmap source) 
    {

        // get image size
        int width = source.getWidth();
        int height = source.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];

        // get pixel array from source
        source.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        // random object
        Random random = new Random();

        int R, G, B, index = 0, thresHold = 50;
        // iteration through pixels


        for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {

                // get current index in 2D-matrix

                index = y * width + x;              
                // get color
                R = Color.red(pixels[index]);
                G = Color.green(pixels[index]);
                B = Color.blue(pixels[index]);
                // generate threshold
                thresHold = random.nextInt(COLOR_MAX );
                if(R > thresHold && G > thresHold && B > thresHold) {
                    pixels[index] = Color.rgb(COLOR_MAX, COLOR_MAX, COLOR_MAX);
                }                           
            }
        }
        // output bitmap                
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        bmOut.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"processed",10).show();
        return bmOut;


    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I actually read about this the other day. You can use a particle system for Android. A library that can assist with that is found here - https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids

Answer (score 0):

Well I've just find the solution.
The source is here: [code link](http://code.google.com/p/android-30days-apps/source/browse/trunk/08day/src/com/bakhtiyor/android/snowfall/?r=27)

The main idea is SnowFallView extends View, and overriding onDraw(Canvas canvas) event, where we drawing our snow flakes drawables.

The code is just tested and works well.